# File lines are not parsed completely when passed clrsh command through .sh file

Tags: shell, aix

I have a test.txt file with the below content:

```
script_initiate.log
script_stop.log
```

I need to find the md5 values on both target and cluster server, for the above listed .log files.

I have written a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='test.txt'
cat $filename | while read line;do
 clrsh server1 csum -h MD5 $line
done
```

This code picks only the 1st line of test.txt file. That is script_initiate.log. (for cluster)

The same code when used for target server reads both the lines of test.txt file. That is script_initiate.log and script_stop.log.

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='test.txt'
cat $filename | while read line;do
 csum -h MD5 $line
done
```

Why such a difference?

Any idea on this would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clrsh` is reading from stdin. The second line of `cat $filename` is redirected to clrsh and `while` doesn't see it.
`ssh` has a similar issue, what can be solved with the parameter `-i`.